# To change icon and text-color of button on mouse hover in menu component

Tags: css, angular-material

I am using **Menu with icons** component in my project.On mouse hovering the menu items(ex: edit) **i want to change both the text and icon color**,something like this.

[image]

But i am able to give only **background-color** on mouse hover but unable to change the **text-color** on mouse hover.

[image]

I tried giving **color: !important;** also, still no result.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gytsqs-rtyy41?file=app%2Fmenu-icons-example.html) link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use code as below:**

```
.mat-menu-item:hover{
  background-color:grey;
  color: purple;
}
.mat-menu-item:hover .mat-icon{
  color: purple;
}
```

**output:**

[image]

**see here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gytsqs-hh8mtq?file=app/menu-icons-example.html**

Comment: tell me for mre help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only this was issue. If any issue arises surely i will ping you back.

Comment: happy to help:)

Answer (score 1):

put on your css man! here's the code.

```
 .mat-menu-item:hover{
      color: blue;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple code change background color..

```
.mat-menu-item:hover{
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```